# Howto get newest dataset with SQL join?

Tags: sql, join

I have got the following join:

```
SELECT  l.cFirma AS Lieferant,
        SUM(la.fEKNetto) AS Verbindlichkeiten,
        l.kLieferant AS Lieferanten_ID,
        100 - gk1.fFaktor * 100 AS Grundkondition,
        MAX(gk1.dDatum) AS Datum
FROM    tBestellung b, tArtikel a, tBestellpos p, tLieferant l, tLiefArtikel la, tGrundkondition gk1
WHERE   
        CAST('01.01.2010' AS DATETIME) <= CAST(b.dErstellt AS DATETIME)
        AND b.cType = 'B' 
        AND p.tBestellung_kBestellung = b.kBestellung
        AND a.kArtikel = p.tArtikel_kArtikel
        AND l.kLieferant = la.tLieferant_KLieferant
        AND a.kArtikel = la.tArtikel_kArtikel
        AND gk1.tLieferant_kLieferant = l.kLieferant
GROUP BY l.kLieferant, cFirma, gk1.fFaktor
ORDER BY Verbindlichkeiten DESC, Lieferant
```

Please fokus on the table "tGrundkondition" alias gk1. There is a DATETIME column called "dDatum" and a foreign key "tLieferant_kLieferant".

Now I need only the latest data from this table, joined with the other stuff. I already used the MAX(gk1.dDatum) function, but I still get all entries of gk1. I need only the latest (with the highest dDate). Actually I don't need to output the date but only to filter the data.

I'm running this statement on Microsoft SQL Server via ODBC. Do you need any further information?

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a correlated subquery, for example add the following:

```
WHERE gk1.DATUM = (SELECT MAX(SUB.DATUM) FROM tGrundkondition SUB
    WHERE SUB.tLieferant_kLieferant = l.kLieferant)
```

I am not sure this is 100% correct because I don't know your table structure, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks this was it. Thanks to the others answerers, too. But This solution returns the latest entry for all tLieferant while the other asnwers only return the latest of all (just one row).

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
SELECT  l.cFirma AS Lieferant,
        SUM(la.fEKNetto) AS Verbindlichkeiten,
        l.kLieferant AS Lieferanten_ID,
        100 - gk1.fFaktor * 100 AS Grundkondition,
        gk1.dDatum AS Datum
FROM    tBestellung b, tArtikel a, tBestellpos p, tLieferant l, tLiefArtikel la, tGrundkondition gk1
WHERE   
        CAST('01.01.2010' AS DATETIME) <= CAST(b.dErstellt AS DATETIME)
        AND b.cType = 'B' 
        AND p.tBestellung_kBestellung = b.kBestellung
        AND a.kArtikel = p.tArtikel_kArtikel
        AND l.kLieferant = la.tLieferant_KLieferant
        AND a.kArtikel = la.tArtikel_kArtikel
        AND gk1.tLieferant_kLieferant = l.kLieferant
        AND gk1.dDatum = (SELECT MAX(dDatum) from _ITS TABLE_)
GROUP BY l.kLieferant, cFirma, gk1.fFaktor
ORDER BY Verbindlichkeiten DESC, Lieferant
```

I don't know if it works on SQL SERVER.... but I used a lot on DB2

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  l.cFirma AS Lieferant,
        SUM(la.fEKNetto) AS Verbindlichkeiten,
        l.kLieferant AS Lieferanten_ID,
        100 - gk1.fFaktor * 100 AS Grundkondition,
        gk1.dDatum AS Datum
FROM    (
        SELECT  TOP 1 *
        FROM    tGrundkondition
        ORDER BY
                dDatum DESC
        ) gk1,
        tBestellung b, tArtikel a, tBestellpos p, tLieferant l, tLiefArtikel la
WHERE   
        CAST('01.01.2010' AS DATETIME) <= CAST(b.dErstellt AS DATETIME)
        AND b.cType = 'B' 
        AND p.tBestellung_kBestellung = b.kBestellung
        AND a.kArtikel = p.tArtikel_kArtikel
        AND l.kLieferant = la.tLieferant_KLieferant
        AND a.kArtikel = la.tArtikel_kArtikel
        AND gk1.tLieferant_kLieferant = l.kLieferant
GROUP BY l.kLieferant, cFirma, gk1.fFaktor
ORDER BY Verbindlichkeiten DESC, Lieferant
```